# Pure CSS Box Corner Decoration

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I was recently thinking about potentially interesting interface design ideas, and one idea that came to mind was a kind of futuristic looking box-based design in which elements would have thin and semi-transparent border lines with small opaque boxes at the corners.

The problem with that for me was thinking of a pure CSS solution for it because I didn't want to add any additional tags in the HTML, and through CSS I thought it would work with pseudo-classes but one element would only be able to have two (with `:before` and `:after`)

I'm grateful for any helpful ideas on how one could achieve such a design using only CSS if it's even possible. Thank you in advance.

I added an Image from the Movie "Oblivion". That is roughly how I imagined it.

[image: Example of how what may look]
Probably the best description is the part around "Tour Code_"

Comment: You would be expected to show what you had tried and why it didn't work. **TL/DR-** Your question is to broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm editing it now :D

Comment: ...with what you had tried in a JSFiddle demo...right? If not, it's still off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know @c-smile has already answered your question, but you can achieve this without images using only CSS. Like so:

```css
body{
 background-color:black;
}
.dots {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 margin:10px;
 border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.dots:before, .dots:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top:-5px;
 height: calc(100% + 10px);
 width: 10px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 5px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 5px),linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 5px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 5px);
 background-size: 10px 10px;
 background-position: top center, bottom center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dots:before {
 left: -5px;
}
.dots:after {
 right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Granted it uses gradients so you may need to be careful with browser compatibility, but it's pure css as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Check CSS border images samples here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image